# Security Token Service could not activated

Tags: 2013, security-token-service

> The requested service, 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas'
>   could not be activated.

I did everything what is written here at this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2520344

But still this message appears sometimes. What can do to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: What if you copy / paste that URL in à browser ?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Type iisreset on dos command line. 
Your reclycle application pool is still keeping wrong information even if your application pool stop and re-start. So, the best solutions is resetting your IIS.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons why the Security Token Service doesn't start. For example, the service account doesn't have the correct permissions (Logon as a Batch Job for Application Pool).

In the ULS Logs you will probably find more, and also check the System Log of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the password of the Identity of the application pool "SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool" was changed.. and then updated it.